# track message reports using Multicast ID on google firebase in php

Tags: javascript, php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to track delivery report of a particular message that have been sent via **FCM** to android device, i found we can add `delivery_receipt_requested` to track delivery and i have added that my json data as follows,

```
{"to":"KEY",
  "data":{
       "data":{
           "title":"test message",
           "message":"sent",
           "image":null}
        },
  "notification":{
           "delivery_receipt_requested":true
         }
  }
```

and i receive a response

```
{"multicast_id":6417448921485349071,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"false"}]}
```

In php or javascript i need something like if we pass that multicast_id need to get the current status of the text. I found it was almost nightmare to get the desired result, but its not impossible is there anyway guys?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to manually ask the FCM server about the status of the sent message.

Based from your post, it seems you already did your homework on checking the FCM service. Implementing the delivery receipts is the only way (AFAIK) that you could attain the behavior you mentioned in your post.

Implementing the delivery receipt not only needs the `delivery_receipt_requested` parameter in your payload, you have to implement an XMPP server protocol as well. Along with the Upstream Messaging part on your client app (for the `ack`nowledgement part).